# When trying to enter a ctrl sequence I affected the screen display

Tags: visual-studio-code

While coding I hit some ctrl keys and totally lost my screen display.  The font size has to be 60px!  Removed Vs code from Control Panel and deleted settings.json.  Downloaded and installed latest Vs code.  When Vs code was brought up I started entering values.  Added values from saved settings.json file before deletion.  Problem returned.

Deleted vscode program via Control Panel, deleted settings.json.
Downloaded and installed latest release of Windows 10 VSCode
Started reentering settings.json values.
Problem returned.  Feel like it is a UI problem??

```
{
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
// Controls the font size in pixels.
"editor.fontSize": 8,
// Controls if the editor should automatically adjust the indentation when
// users type, paste or move lines. Indentation rules of the language must be
//  available.
"editor.autoIndent": true,
// The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overridden based
//  on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is on.
"editor.detectIndentation": true,
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"editor.tabSize": 4,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Oceanic Next (dimmed bg)",
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"files.autoSave": "off",
"window.zoomLevel": 21,
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
// Enable/disable built-in PHP validation.
"php.validate.enable": true,
// Points to the PHP executable.
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/Program Files/PHP/php.exe",
"phpfmt.php_bin": "\"C:\\Program Files\\PHP\\php.exe\"",
```

}

Tried to include several screen dumps but could not figure out how to do it.
I can best describe the problem as trying to display a 60" TV screen on a 15" Laptop Monitor.

Comment: I deleted my latest settings.json and brought up VS Code successfully.  Added php.validate.executablePath and phpfmt.php_bin vales without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it was this line in settings.json:

```
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
```

Setting it to the following solved the issue:

```
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
```